# Laravel - Consulta con tabla pivot

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, laravel-7, laravel-8

Buenas tengo 3 entidades que són **Recetas**, **Ingredientes**  y **RecetasIngredientes**.

Ingredientes : es una tabla maestra de productos.
Recetas : es una tabla maestra de recetas.
RecetasIngredientes : es una tabla pivot con un "ID de receta" y un "ID de ingrediente"

Un ejemplo gráfico seria.

**Ingredientes**
ID : 1
Nombre : Arroz

**Recetas**
ID : 100
Nombre : Arroz con papas

**RecetasIngredientes**
id : 1000, receta_id = 100 , ingrediente_id = 1

Dicho esto tengo los modelos de esta forma

**Modelo Recetas**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Recetas extends Model
{

protected $guarded = ['id'];


public function ingredientes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Ingredientes::class,'receta_id','id');
}

public function recetasIngredientes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(RecetasIngredientes::class,'receta_id','id');
}

}
```

**Modelo Ingredientes**

```
 <?php
    
    namespace App;
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    
    class Ingredientes extends Model
    {
    
        protected $table = 'ingredientes';
    
        protected $fillable = [
            'real_id', 'descripcion'
        ];
    
        public function recetas()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(Recetas::class,'id','receta_id');
        }
    
    }
```

**Modelo RecetasIngredientes**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class RecetasIngredientes extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'recetas_ingredientes';

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function recetasIngredientes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Recetas::class,'id','receta_id');
    }
}
```

Dicho esto, creo que las relaciones las tengo bien.
El problema lo tengo cuando quiero hacer una consulta que sea "Aquellas recetas que tienen este ingrediente X" , por eso me quiero apoyar en la tabla intermedia RecetasIngredientes con una consulta tipo esta

```
    $recetas = Recetas::where('id','>=',0)
        ->with(['recetasIngredientes'])
        ->where('recetas_ingredientes.ingrediente_id',$ingrediente_id)
        ->get();
```

También he probado esta forma pero si tengo 100 recetas en la BD me devuelve las 100, da igual que ingrediente_id le pase a la función siempre me devuelve las 100 que tengo en la BD.

```
$recetas = Recetas::with(['recetasIngredientes' => function ($query) use ($ingrediente_id) {
    $query->where('ingrediente_id', '=', $ingrediente_id);
}])->get();
```

**Añado como tengo la migración de la tabla pivot.**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('recetas_ingredientes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('receta_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('ingrediente_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('receta_id')->references('id')->on('recetas')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('ingrediente_id')->references('real_id')->on('ingredientes')->unsigned();
    });
}
```

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estás usando las relaciones de Eloquent adecuadas, dado el escenario que expones debes emplear a [**belongsToMany**](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many), pues pues *hasMany* sería en una relación *uno a muchos*.

Tampoco (*aunque no es incorrecto*) tener un modelo para la tabla intermedia, lo que si es de mencionar es que si vas a crearlo entonces debes sujetarte a lo indicado por la [doc. oficial al respecto](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models).

Dicho lo anterior, entonces deberás considerar los siguientes cambios:

1. Elimina el modelo para la tabla intermedia
2. En los 2 modelos restantes declara las siguientes relaciones:

   - Modelo Ingrediente:

     ```
     public function recetas()
     {
         return $this->belongsToMany(Receta::class, 'recetas_ingredientes');
     }
     ```
   - Modelo Receta:

     ```
     public function ingredientes()
     {
         return $this->belongsToMany(Ingrediente::class, 'recetas_ingredientes');
     }
     ```
3. Ahora para la consulta en cuestión podemos hacer lo siguiente:

   ```
    Receta::query()
            ->whereHas('ingredientes', function ($query) use($ingrediente_id){
                $query->whereIngredienteId($ingrediente_id);
            })
            ->with(['ingredientes' => function ($query) use($ingrediente_id){
                $query->whereIngredienteId($ingrediente_id);
            }])->get();
   ```

*Extra*

Incluso puedes [crear un método](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#filtering-queries-via-intermediate-table-columns) que responda directamente a entregar esta información en tu modelo *`Receta`* y solo usarlo cuando así sea requerido por ejemplo:

```
public function conIngredienteFiltrado()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Ingrediente::class, 'recetas_ingredientes')->wherePivot('ingrediente_id', $variableConEseValor);
}
```

Comment: Gracias @BetaM por la ayuda prestada, acabo de editar la 1º página con la migration de la tabla intermedia, he hecho los cambios que me has dicho pero a pesar de esto la consulta me sigue devolviento todos los items de la tabla receta, independientmente que valor le pase a  "$ingrediente_id"

Comment: Muchas gracias @BetaM ahora si, 1000 gracias